# Jquery Array Contains

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array that all the name of all selected check boxes. How can I check if that array contains specific value other than given string.

```
var selected_options = $('input[checked=checked]').map( function() { 
    return $(this).attr('name');
}).get();
```

How can I check if the array selected_options has other elements other than lets say 'CancelTerms'?

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: `var exists = selected_options.indexOf('CancelTerms')  > -1`

Comment: `$('input[checked=checked][name="CancelTerms"]') .length > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is the need to create an array for that. Just filter out element not having a certain name value using [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with [`:not()` pseudo-class selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) ( or [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method ) and get its length.

```
if($('input[checked=checked]:not([name="CancelTerms"])') .length > 0){
   // code
}
```

---

If you would like to do it with the array then use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```
if(selected_options.some(function(v){ return v != "CancelTerms"; })){
   // code
}
```

or [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method can be used.

```
if(selected_options.filter(function(v){ return v!= "CancelTerms"; }).legth){
   // code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer really appreciate. I have three values to check how can I do that ?

Comment: @user4676307: inside bot `,` seperate `:not([name="CancelTerms"],[.....],[......])`

Comment: @user4676307 `some(function(v){ return  ["CancelTerms", "namme1","name2"].indexOf(v) >-1 ; })`

Comment: @user4676307 : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the length of array excluding specificvalues occurence count in it:

```
var selectedcount = selected_options.reduce(function(n, "CancelTerms") {
      return n + (val === search);
}, 0);
if(selected_options.length - selectedcount  > 0){
   //other elements exists
}
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
var selected_options = ["str1","CancelTerms"];
var selectedcount = selected_options.indexOf('CancelTerms') > -1 ? 1 : 0;
if(selected_options.length - selectedcount  > 0){
   console.log("other elements exists")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @eisbehr: same thing. `str1` exists.